# Enterprise library 5.0 Close active connection forcefully

Tags: c#, ado.net, enterprise-library

How can I close Database connection forcefully?

The sample code I'm using to create connection is:

```
class Customer{
     private readonly Database _db;
      public Customer(){
            _db = = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase(_userSettings.ConnstringName);
       }

   .. stuff to use this connection..

}
```

Comment: any final solution with full source code sample working about it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the code (.. stuff to use this connection..) inside a `using` block, which will ensure the connection is closed. For example:

```
using (DbCommand command = _db.GetStoredProcCommand(sprocName, parameters))    
{
```

and:

```
using (IDataReader rdr = _db.ExecuteReader(command))
{
```

[Using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) blocks are a nice way of ensuring resources are closed properly:

> The using statement allows the
>   programmer to specify when objects
>   that use resources should release
>   them.

Otherwise, you have to explicitly call the `Close()` method on the connection object:

```
if (command.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            command.Connection.Close();
```

Comment: I can't do that because I m not creating the connection.  the is used by **cmd = _db.GetStoredProcCommand(query)** or **_db.Get..SomeThing** or **_db._db.ExecuteReader / ExecuteDatase**

Comment: You're right. I just updated the code snippet to reflect the real EL syntax. The benefit of a using block is the point.

Comment: Another thing is when the Object ( this case Customer) get disposed all the resource consumed by Object ( may be the connection) get disposed ( connection get closed..) am I correct..?

Comment: Not necessarily. Can you post some code so I can understand the context?

Comment: @Joe R: can u pls take a look at [What is difference between Oracle session and Oracle Connection Or Both are the same..?] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5717927/what-is-difference-between-oracle-session-and-oracle-connection-or-both-are-the-s)

Comment: Ok, you would need to make sure that the connection is properly closed. Just allowing Customer to go out of scope is not enough. I've added an answer to that question.

Comment: any final solution with full source code sample working about it ?