# What is difference between Oracle session and Oracle Connection Or Both are the same..?

Tags: ado.net, enterprise-library, odp.net, enterprise-library-5

I m using the Enterprise lib to connect Oracle Database

```
class Customer{
     private readonly Database _db;
      public Customer(){
            _db = = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase(_userSettings.ConnstringName);
       }

   .. stuff to use this connection..

}
```

When I run  the application and opens multiple screen now Oracle show multiple session 
 for same Application

Also I tried by changing code as

```
class Customer{
         private readonly Database _db;
          public Customer(){
                _db = = (_userSettings.GetInstance().GetDatabase);
           }

       .. stuff to use this connection..

    }
```

*_userSettings is a singleton object*

But same thing happens..?

**What's going wrong?**

Pls Help

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is too little information here to give an answer. We'd need to see more about your connection code. What version of oracle are you using?

What may be happening, is you may not be setting a timeout on your user's session, so that these sessions you keep making are staying active.

Comment: **the connection string i m using is:** connectionString="DATA SOURCE=xyz:1521/orcl;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;USER ID=user;password=pwd" providerName="Oracle.DataAccess.Client"  **also I tried with**  connectionString="DATA SOURCE=xyz:1521/orcl;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;USER ID=user;password=pwd;Min Pool Size=10;Connection Lifetime=60;Connection Timeout=60;Incr Pool Size=5; Decr Pool   Size=2" providerName="Oracle.DataAccess.Client"

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly close the connection using Close() or use a using block to ensure the unmanaged code is garbage collected properly.